# What does asynchronously recursive mean in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

In Mongoose documentation for validation they say "**Validation is asynchronously recursive: when you call Model#save, sub-document validation is executed. If an error happens, your Model#save callback receives it**"

What do they mean by it? Suppose I have 5 validations than will they be run in parallel or series? Or is they get called in series with a callback that is received by the model save method?
Please help me understand this? I know its a very easy question But I could not get any help from searching and all. So please.

Comment: Still Waiting for someone who can through more light on the specific feature of mongoose.

Answer (score 1):

It means that, despite the fact that you have multiple events triggering "simultaneously" each method maintains it's own state, and it's own error handling steps separately for each request and for each step.

Consider this example in which we need disk information to initialize a database query.  Each successive step is an asynchronous operation, that calls a callback.

```
function dataBaseQuerys(someQuerys) {
    function queryDatabase(someQuery) {

        if(someQuery === undefined) return;

        fs.readFile('someFile', function (err, data) {
            'use strict';

            var myQuery = someQuery + data;

            query(myQuery, function (err, qData) {
                doSomethingWithTheQuery(qData);
                queryDatabase(someQuerys.pop());//Recursion(behaves iteratively, but with async calls!  No for loop necessary)
            });
        });
    }

    queryDatabase(someQuerys.pop());
}
```

Now consider the following example in which we don't take advantage of async recursion.

```
function dataBaseQuerys(someQuerys) {

    for(var i = 0; i < someQuerys.size; i++) {
        var fileData = fs.readFileSync('someFile');

        var myQuery = someQuerys[i] + fileData;

        doSomethingWithTheQuery(querySync(myQuery));//Finding a DB module that does a "querySync" is probably not possible, but assume it is.
    }
}
```

These two examples do the same thing.  The iterative one is a little more difficult to get the error handling correct, and try/catch in javascript is bad because it disallows optimization.  The recursive one, the syntax is a little tricky with getting the closure data for the "nextQuery" object and such, but it doesn't clog the event loop, which is priceless for performance.  All the developers are telling you is that they used the first example.

EDIT: I'm gonna hand hold a little bit here and answer your bullet points as they pertain to these examples:

What do they mean by it? Honestly can't get more specific here... my example explicitly outlines the idiom they are using.

Suppose I have 5 validations than will they be run in parallel or series? -They will run in series, asynchronously.  This is the point of the "recursion".  Each point in code is guaranteed to run in order, but other things can happen in the background, just not things involving any of the callback sequences the queries are implementing.

Or is they get called in series with a callback that is received by the model save method?  -YES

Please help me understand this? - If this does not help, you need to ask a more specific question.  Also, if you don't see how the logic I laid out in my examples covers all of these questions, you should spend a little more time wrapping your head around async "event based callbacks".  If you're accustomed to C-style logic flow it can be hard to wrap your head around, I've been there and wish someone at the time would have told me the same.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just to clear out one more thing does it mean that calling fn1, fn2, and fn3 in the async recursive manner with a callback to a function which waits for all 3 to be completed would mean that fn 2 doesn't wait for fn 1 to complete and same for fn3? I m basically asking than the time taken to complete all the functions would be sum of each or the maximum time of anyone??

Comment: It would mean that it's the sum of each.  The benefit you get from async recursion isn't that an individual request happens faster, but rather that other things can happen in the background while the requests are taking place.  For example, you could have several fn1s happening(obj1.fn1, obj2.fn1, obj3.fn1) could all be going at once(though not within singular calls to the first example function, recursion prevents this, but doesn't keep you from calling dataBaseQuerys multiple times successively on different arrays!!!), but you would never have:(obj1.fn1, obj1.fn2) happening at the same time.

Comment: Even if you attempted such, by calling dataBaseQuerys twice succesively on the same array.  What you would end up with is obj1.fn1, and copyOfObj1.fn2 potentially executing at the same time.  Each within a different closure scope.

Comment: What you are saying here is just in general sense or specific to the Mongoose Validations? I need it be specific to mongoose validation.

Comment: I cannot speak as to the bugginess or non-bugginess of Mongoose Validations.  This is of course in a general sense, the example doesn't involve a reference to mongoose code, it is a general example of asynchronous recursion.  That being said, async recursion can only mean async recursion, and is a well known idiom.  If it doesn't work like this, it is because the mongoose code is broken or documentation incorrect.

Comment: Ok Thanks. But I am still not accepting your answer since I am waiting for a more specific answer. Thanks.

Comment: In this case you should ask a more specific question, as I cannot honestly see how to answer it more directly...  In certain cases you can logically prove the generic case is equivalent to the specific case, this is one of those cases.  Including Mongoose code would overcomplicate the answer, and would be the only way to make this answer any more specific.